# Static local variables' initialization at program startup

Tags: c++, c++11, initialization

[cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/storage_duration#Static_local_variables) states:

> Variables declared at block scope with the specifier static or thread_local (since C++11) have static or thread (since C++11) storage duration but are initialized the first time control passes through their declaration (**unless their initialization is zero- or constant-initialization**, which can be performed before the block is first entered).

My question is about that "unless" part - can you give examples of code where the static local variable is zero- and constant-initialized? Can class objects (e.g. `MyClass obj;`) be zero- or constant-initialized? If so, does that mean their constructor would be called before `main()` starts?

Comment: I think the docs mean that there has to be some `constexpr` (or at least `const`) way of doing that operation... I'm not sure though...

Comment: Did you read the [cppreference description of constant-initialization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constant_initialization), which is linked from the quote you include? If so, what part of it was confusing?

Comment: @rici To be honest, I was more confused by the [zero-initialization article](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/zero_initialization), e.g.: "Zero-initialization is performed [...]: 1) For every named variable with static [...] storage duration that is not subject to constant initialization, before any other initialization." Wouldn't that mean that **all** static local variables are initialized at program startup? Obviously, that's not the case but that means I don't understand the above statement correctly.

Comment: @nps: it's correct that they are all initialized at program startup, by being placed in memory initialized to zero by the loader. Search for "bss segment" for more information about how this is accomplished on some operating systems.

Comment: Note that zero initialisation does not involve calling a constructor. It basically means ensuring that the memory occupied by the object is cleared to zero.

Comment: Ahh! That's probably what I was missing. Are all static local variables guaranteed then to always have their constructors called upon first function call (and not earlier)?

Comment: @NPS: Unless they are constant-initialised :-), like it says in the cppreference paragraph you quoted. (See "constexpr constructor", which has evolved since C++11.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> can you give examples of code where the static local variable is zero- and constant-initialized?

In the below given example, the local static variable `n` satisfies both the conditions for constant initialization so that here the "unless" part in your quoted statement also holds.

```
int main()
{
     static const int i = 5; //both conditions for constant initialization are satisfied so that the "unless" part of your quoted statement also holds
}
```

---

> A variable or temporary object `obj` is **constant-initialized** if
>
> - **either it has an initializer** or its default-initialization results in some initialization being performed, and
> - **its initialization full-expression is a constant expression**, except that if obj is an object, that full-expression may also invoke constexpr constructors for obj and its subobjects even if those objects are of non-literal class types (since C++11).

---

> Can class objects (e.g. `MyClass obj;`) be zero- or constant-initialized?

Yes class objects can also be constant initialized.

```
struct Custom
{
    constexpr Custom()
    {
        
    }
};
int main()
{
     static constexpr Custom obj;//here also both conditions for constant initialization are satisfied
}
```

---

Note also that initialization does not necessarily implies that a constructor must be used. For example, in `#include <string> std::string s; int main(){}` the `s` is first is **zero initialized** and then default initialized(using the default ctor). This means that the first initialization step here, does not use any ctor.

Comment: Can class objects be zero-initialized?

Comment: @NPS Yes class objects can be zero initialized. For example, `#include <string> std::string s; int main(){}`. In the above [example](https://onlinegdb.com/1DSKEm97n) the string variable `s` is first zero initialized.

Comment: Can static local class objects be zero-initialized?

Comment: @NPS Yes static local class objects can also be zero-initialized. For example, `class Custom{Custom(){}};int main(){static Custom obj;}`. In the above [example](https://onlinegdb.com/3v5bdsW5d), `obj` will first be zero initialized.

Comment: Your answer is more comprehensive so I would like to accept it but for me it's missing one key information - that initialization does not necessarily involve calling a constructor - which for me was what caused the confusion. Could you please include it (so it doesn't get lost in the comments for other people)? Also possibly the other bits from your comments here.

Comment: @NPS Done, added that at the end of my answer as a note with example.

Answer (score 1):

According to this: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/zero_initialization

> Zero-initialization is performed [...] For every named variable with static [...] storage duration that is not subject to constant initialization, **before any other initialization.**

So in this context

```cpp
int main() {
    ...
    static MyClass a;
    ...
}
```

zero-initialization of `a` can be performed before `main()` starts, but its constructor will be called inside of `main()` as expected.